# Get sharing status of a file using google drive sdk

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using google drive sdk to get a list of files. How do I get the sharing status of file? I just want the public files.

I don't see any field for this in File resource https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files

Comment: looks like I have to use this api https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list for every file